# Бот для вк паблика

Tags: python, бот

Ребята подскажите как это сделать вообще?
Суть такая. Есть написанный бот для паблика(отвечает на сообщения).Когда запускаю с ноута, то все работает. 
Но ведь ноут не будет же все время работать 24\7. 
вопрос? Как и на какой хостинг залить чтобы работало(для тестов подойдет бесплатный, а в дальнейшем перейти на платный)
Где можно посмотреть как это делается?

Comment: На любой, на котором бот будет способен запуститься и не упасть от нехватки оперативки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть сервис https://www.pythonanywhere.com/, загружаешь проект и запускаешь, бесплатный хостинг на 3 месяца, каждые 3 месяца нужно заходить и нажимать продлить на 3 месяца

Comment: Но можно сделать таск, который будет каждый день продлевать сам себя и приложение.

Answer (score 0):

webhost000 - бесплатный, выдает бесплатный ssl сертификат, у меня там стоял бот. Но не надежный, бывало, что падал сайт и бот не отвечал

eternalhost - крутая штука, один раз заплатил - пользуешься вечно, +бесплатный сертификат есть. Купил себе, относительно не дорого.  !надо купить домен, даже минимальный есть за 60 рублей.

zzz.com.ua - бесплатный, хороший, но в Украине, может с вк не работать

Comment: Можешь пожалуйста чуть подробнее рассказать как на eternalhost  закинуть и запустить?

Comment: @Arexils, да, конечно, напиши мне в телеграм https://t.me/Solarisedigle